# debug websocket to connect python to alpaca broker

Tags: debugging, websocket, send, alpaca

i receive this error

```
Connessione WebSocket aperta
send: b'\x8a\x80\x1fB\x9d\xb9'
DEBUG:websocket:send: b'\x8a\x80\x1fB\x9d\xb9'
send: b'\x8a\x80l\xcf\x7f\xe9'
DEBUG:websocket:send: b'\x8a\x80l\xcf\x7f\xe9'
send: b'\x8a\x80|\xa2m\xb3'
DEBUG:websocket:send: b'\x8a\x80|\xa2m\xb3'
send: b'\x8a\x80\x85\xb0\xb5\xf6'
DEBUG:websocket:send: b'\x8a\x80\x85\xb0\xb5\xf6'
```

i am connecting a trading sistem to alpaca broker.
websocket send but alpaca does not receive.

how can i resolve?